# How to use linq `Except` with multiple properties with different class?

Tags: c#, linq, except, iequalitycomparer

I am trying to learn the `Linq/Lambda` expressions and was stuck at somewhere.

**What I was Doing**

I have created two classes with properties which have some common properties in them. The classes are like(It's test code).

```
class TestA
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public TestA(int id, int procid, string category)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.ProductID = procid;
            this.Category = category;
        }
    }

    class TestB
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

        public TestB(int procid, string category)
        {
            this.ProductID = procid;
            this.Category = category;
        }
    }
```

Then I created the two list for them as,

```
        List<TestA> testListA = new List<TestA>();
        List<TestB> testListB = new List<TestB>();
        TestA t1 = new TestA(1, 254, "ProductA");
        TestA t2 = new TestA(1, 236, "ProductA");
        TestA t3 = new TestA(1, 215, "ProductB");
        TestA t4 = new TestA(1, 175, "ProductB");
        TestA t5 = new TestA(1, 175, "ProductC");
        testListA.Add(t1);
        testListA.Add(t2);
        testListA.Add(t3);
        testListA.Add(t4);
        testListA.Add(t5);

        TestB tt1 = new TestB(254, "ProdcutA");
        TestB tt2 = new TestB(215, "ProductB");
        TestB tt3 = new TestB(175, "ProductC");
        testListB.Add(tt3);
        testListB.Add(tt2);
        testListB.Add(tt1);
```

Now for result I wanted `t2` as it's `ProductID` match is not in the `testListB` 
And `t4` as it has matching `ProductID` in `testListB` but don't have the same `Category`.
1) I need a `List<A>` of every record which: No longer has a `ProductID` held in the testListB

which I can get as ,

```
  testListA.Select(x => x.ProductID).Except(testListB.Select(x => x.ProductID ));
```

2)No longer has a record which has a matching `ProductID` and `Category` in testListB

which I Can get using,

```
   testListA.Where(a => testListB.Any(b => a.ProductID == b.ProductID && a.Category != b.Category));
```

**My Question **
Is it possible two make single linq expression to get result.I thought of using the  implement `IEqualityComparer` but I am not sure how to implement the `GetHashCode` it for two different type of classes. So either combining the above query into single query or any other way to  impliment custom `Comparer` for two different Type of classes. Or is there any other simple way?

Comment: I do not see any evidence in your code of you, using GetHashCode . I know this is a delicate matter myself, but if yo want us to help you out, you must at least submit code that is SUPPOSED to use GetHashCode.

Comment: As I said I am currently using two seprate queries to get result. I thought of implementing the `IEqualityComparer ` but I was not sure how to implement the `GetHashCode ` so I din't included here. As you Know if you implement the `IEqualityComparer `. Then you have to implement `GetHashCode `

Comment: Sorry, while reading more throw, your post was most informative, so my  apologies .I understand you want to implement  IEqualityComparer.

Comment: So, if you post your implementation of IEqualityComparer, I will help you out!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have said that you need only these objects from `testListA`:

- there is not matching `ProductID` in `testListB`
- there is existing mathing `ProductID`, but with different `Category`

So, your filter must be:

`!testListB.Any(b => a.ProductID == b.ProductID && a.Category == b.Category)`

So, change your code as:

```
testListA.Where(a => !testListB.Any(b => a.ProductID == b.ProductID && a.Category == b.Category));
```

---

***Second approach:***

Or you can create a new `List<TestA>` from the second list:

```
 var secondListA = testListB.Select(x=> new TestA(){Category=x.Category, ProductID=x.ProductID}).ToList();
```

And then create your `Comparer`:

```
sealed class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<TestA>
{
    public bool Equals(TestA x, TestA y)
    {
        if (x == null)
            return y == null;
        else if (y == null)
            return false;
        else
            return x.ProductID == y.ProductID && x.Category == y.Category;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(TestA obj)
    {
        return obj.ProductID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And use [`Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb336390%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) overload which produces the set difference of two sequences by using the specified `IEqualityComparer<T>` to compare values.:

```
var result = testListA.Except(secondListA, new MyComparer ()).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for quick answer. Now when I Look at the expression. Ifeel dumb to not realising to use the `where ` with `||` thanks. But I was just wondring is it possible to implement `IEqualityComparer `  for two diffrent type of classes.

Comment: @user2745246 No, `IEqualityComparer<T>` is an interface for an object that performs the comparison on two objects of the type `T`.

Comment: Yes Thanks I just started reading about it. I got it now how that works. I will try your way and try to find if there is any other way to get it as I am trying to learn the linq. And I will wait for 2 or 3 days to get the more answers with diffrent aproaches if not any new approch then I will Accept it as answer. Thanks for answer once again.

Comment: @user2745246 Thanks. By the way, I have updated my answer. The filtering could be more simple. **Also**, if you want to try different ways for learnign purposes, then you can try my update.

Comment: Nice I did the same thing when trying new approches. Thanks for the update though. I wish I had more than one upvote option.

Comment: @user2745246 Glad for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example implementing IEqualityComparer. It should work as a concept for your purpose:

```
private class PKExclusiveComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : DataRow
{
  public bool Equals(T x, T y)
  {
    bool result = true;
    foreach (DataColumn col in (x as DataRow).Table.Columns)
    {
      if (!(x as DataRow).Table.PrimaryKey.Contains(col))
      {
        result &= x[col].Equals(y[col]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  public int GetHashCode(T x)
  {
    string code = string.Empty;
    foreach (DataColumn col in (x as DataRow).Table.Columns)
    {
      if (!(x as DataRow).Table.PrimaryKey.Contains(col))
      {
        code += x[col].ToString();
      }
    }
    return code.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Comment: Ouups, some formating errors. anyway, My idea, which I used  hundreds of  times, is to get a "unique string" and then get a hash.

Comment: I am sorry but how can it work. Here `T` is type of `DataRow` that one single type. My problem is my `T` type can be either `TestA` or `TestB` not a one type as mentioned above. As the `GetHashcode` get only one type as argument I am not sure how can I pass my two diffrent type of class to the `GetHashCode`

Comment: Well, As I said, it's a concept, not an exact solution for your case.

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Class dosyalar
    Public adi As String
    Public tarih As DateTime
End Class


Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim dosyalarList1 As New List(Of dosyalar)
    dosyalarList1.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya1", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 10)})
    dosyalarList1.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya2", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 20)})
    dosyalarList1.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya3", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 30)})
    dosyalarList1.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya4", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 40)})
    dosyalarList1.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya5", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 50)})

    Dim dosyalarList2 As New List(Of dosyalar)
    dosyalarList2.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya1", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 11)})
    dosyalarList2.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya2", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 21)})
    dosyalarList2.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya3", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 30)})
    dosyalarList2.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya4", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 40)})
    dosyalarList2.Add(New dosyalar With {.adi = "dosya5", .tarih = New DateTime(2020, 3, 30, 10, 10, 50)})


    Dim result As List(Of dosyalar) = dosyalarList1.Where(Function(a) Not dosyalarList2.Any(Function(b) a.adi = b.adi AndAlso a.tarih = b.tarih)).ToList

End Sub
```