# linq - How to find if one collection's key columns are a subset of another collection?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm using .NET 4.5 in C#, and I've got two collections of different classes that I'm trying to compare. They have some columns with similar names, but they don't implement a common interface (and can't for coding-standard reasons).

The first class looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
    string Key1 {get; set;}
    string Key2 {get; set;}
    string NotKey {get; set;}
    string AlsoNotKey {get; set;}
}
```

While the second one looks like this:

```
class Bar
{
    string Key1 {get; set;}
    string Key2 {get; set;}
}
```

What I want to do is pass a collection of `Foo` into a method and return `true` when every distinct pair of `Key1` and `Key2` in it has a match in a collection of `Bar` retrieved from a database (via EF), but I can't figure out how to do that.

My first idea looked something like this...

```
//IEnumerable<Foo> foos
//DbSet<Bar> bars
foos.All(foo => foo.Key1 == bars.Key1 && foo.Key2 == bars.Key2)
```

...but it doesn't work because `bars` is a collection too, and I can't just use `Contains()` around each column because then it won't compare both columns as a pair.

In SQL, I could do something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM foos
JOIN bars
ON foos.key1 = bars.key1
AND foos.key2 = bars.key2
```

and compare it to the number of records in `foos` by itself, but how can I translate that to LINQ?

**Edit:** Found this related question. [How to use linq `Except` with multiple properties with different class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782437/how-to-use-linq-except-with-multiple-properties-with-diffrent-class)

Might try something like this, unless there's a better way.

```
foos.All(f => bars.Any(b => f.Key1 == b.Key1 && f.Key2 == b.Key2))
```

Comment: Did you try [LINQ's join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx)? It might do exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: You should write a Join query in Linq to Entities.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896266(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var x = (from f in foos
         join b in bars on new { f.Key1, f.Key2 } equals new { b.Key1, b.Key2 }
         select f).Count();
```

I know it is a long form, but this is the case where it is more descriptive than the short form.

The big assumption is, obviously, that your keys don't duplicate. If they do you will get wrong item count

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
bool IsFooASubsetOfBar(List<Foo> foos, List<Bar> bars)
{
    if (foos == null || bars == null)
        return false;

    return foos.All(foo => bars.Any(bar => bar.Key1 == foo.Key1 && bar.Key2 == foo.Key2));
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>()
            {
                new Bar() { Key1 = "1", Key2 = "1" },
                new Bar() { Key1 = "2", Key2 = "2" },
                new Bar() { Key1 = "3", Key2 = "3" }
            };

List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>()
            {
                new Foo() { Key1 = "2", Key2 = "2" },
                new Foo() { Key1 = "3", Key2 = "3" }
            };

bool b = IsFooASubsetOfBar(foos);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join`, but I wouldn't do a `count`, as that would force you to take into consideration duplicate key tuples. I'd use a `left join` instead:

```
public bool Matches(IEnumerable<Foo> foos, DbSet<Bar> bars)
{
       return (from f in foos
               join b in bars on new {f.Key1, f.Key2} equals new {b.Key1, b.Key2} into fjb
               from match in fjb.DefaultIfEmpty()
               select match != null
               ).All(isMatch => isMatch);       
}
```